# Insertion Sort pt2 -Hackerrank

Tags: java, sorting

can someone please check my code as to why the last index is not working as intended? Any advice on how to improve this is much appreciated.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

public static void insertionSortPart2(int[] ar) {       
 int key;
 int seen;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < ar.length-1; i++){
        key = ar[i];
        seen = i;

        while (seen <ar.length-1 && ar[seen+1]<key){

            ar[seen]= ar[seen+1];
             seen = seen+1;
        }

        ar[seen]=key;
            printArray(ar);
    }  
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   int s = in.nextInt();
   int[] ar = new int[s];
   for(int i=0;i<s;i++){
        ar[i]=in.nextInt(); 
   }
   insertionSortPart2(ar);    

}    
private static void printArray(int[] ar) {
  for(int n: ar){
     System.out.print(n+" ");
  }
    System.out.println("");
 }
}
```

Input (stdin) 6 1 4 3 5 6 2

Your Output (stdout) 1 4 3 5 6 2 1 3 4 5 6 2 1 3 4 5 6 2 1 3 4 5 6 2 1 3 4 5 2 6

Expected Output 1 4 3 5 6 2 1 3 4 5 6 2 1 3 4 5 6 2 1 3 4 5 6 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 Compiler Message Wrong Answer

Comment: have you gone through this with a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it in wrong way. Read the part 1 again.

Assume that first element is sorted. Then try to insert element one by one in sorted list.

Try this:

```
    public static void insertionSortPart2(int[] ar) {
        int key;
        int seen;

        for (int i = 1 ; i < ar.length; i++){
            key = ar[i];
            seen = i;

            while (seen > 0 && ar[seen-1] > key) {
                ar[seen] = ar[seen-1];
                seen = seen - 1;
            }

            ar[seen]=key;
            printArray(ar);
        }
    }
```